# writeTypedList return null List

Tags: android, parcelable

it's been 2 days i'm working on this and as much as i search i did not found answer on this topic so i try here : 
In my writeToParcel method, i'm sending a custom list and that's why i use a writeTypedList method. the proble is, when i use it, it return me a null list . I give you my code :

```
public class Team implements Parcelable {

private List<Player> players;
private String team_name;
private String sport_name;
private String team_leader;
private String training_day;
private String training_hour;

public Team(){
    players = new ArrayList<Player>() ;
    addPlayer(new Player(team_leader));
}


protected Team(String team_name, String sport_name, String team_leader, String training_day, String training_hour) {
    players = new ArrayList<Player>();
    this.team_name = team_name;
    this.sport_name = sport_name;
    this.team_leader = team_leader;
    this.training_day = training_day;
    this.training_hour = training_hour;

    addPlayer(new Player(team_leader));
}

public Team(Parcel in) {

    this();

    team_name = in.readString();
    sport_name = in.readString();
   team_leader= in.readString();
    training_day = in.readString();
    training_hour = in.readString();
    System.out.println("in Team Parcel" +in.toString());
    //ArrayList <Player> tempPlayers = new ArrayList<Player>();
    System.out.println("in Team 2" +players);
    in.readTypedList(players,Player.CREATOR);
    //players = in.createTypedArrayList(Player.CREATOR);
}

public List<Player> getTeam(){
    if(players == null) players = new ArrayList<>();
    return players;
}

public void addPlayer(Player player){
    getTeam().add(player);
}

public static final Creator<Team> CREATOR = new Creator<Team>() {
    @Override
    public Team createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Team(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Team[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Team[size];
    }
};



public String getTeamName() {
    return team_name;
}

public String getSportName() { return sport_name; }

public String getTeamLeader() {
    return team_leader;
}

public String getTrainingDay() {
    return training_day;
}

public String getTrainingHour() {return  training_hour; }

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Team{" +
            "team_name='" + team_name + '\'' +
            ", sport_name='" + sport_name + '\'' +
            ", team_leader ='" + team_leader + '\'' +
            ", training_day=" + training_day +
            ", training_hour=" + training_hour +
            ", players=" + players +
            '}';
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    dest.writeString(team_name);
    dest.writeString(sport_name);
    dest.writeString(team_leader);
    dest.writeString(training_day);
    dest.writeString(training_hour);
    System.out.println("in Team 3" +players);
    dest.writeTypedList(players);
    //System.out.println("in Team 3" +dest);
}
}
```

And now i give you the class Player

```
public class Player implements Parcelable {

private String playerName;
private String playerPosition;
private String playerMail;
private String playerPhone;

public Player(String _playerName){
    this.playerName=_playerName;
    this.playerPosition="";
    this.playerMail = "";
    this.playerPhone = "";
}

public Player(String _playerName, String _playerPosition, String _playerMail, String _playerPhone){
    this.playerName = _playerName;
    this.playerPosition = _playerPosition;
    this.playerMail = _playerMail;
    this.playerPhone = _playerPhone;
}

protected Player(Parcel in) {
    playerName = in.readString();
    playerPosition = in.readString();
    playerMail = in.readString();
    playerPhone = in.readString();
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Player> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Player>() {
    @Override
    public Player createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Player(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Player[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Player[size];
    }
};


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Player{" +
            " PlayerName='" + playerName + '\'' +
            ", PlayerPosition='" + playerPosition + '\'' +
            ", PlayerMail=" + playerMail +
            ", PlayerPhone=" + playerPhone +
            '}';
}


public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}


public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(playerName);
    dest.writeString(playerPosition);
    dest.writeString(playerMail);
    dest.writeString(playerPhone);
}

public String getPlayerName() {
    if(playerName != null)
        return playerName;
    else
        return "";
}

public String getPlayerPosition() {
    if(playerPosition != null)
        return playerPosition;
    else
        return "";
}

public String getPlayerMail() {
    if(playerMail != null)
        return playerMail;
    else
        return "";
}

public String getPlayerPhone() {
    if(playerPhone != null)
        return playerPhone;
    else
        return "";
}
```

}

If you could help me a little, or redirecting me to someone with the same issue that would be nice :)

Comment: Make your life easier with [parceler](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler)